# Excel VBA - Cells with comma delimited data sorted

Tags: vba, excel

I have data:

```
    A          B

1  RED   him, her, kirk

2  BLUE  kirk, rose, jill
```

I want to sort by the B column, create rows for each data point in column B that are comma delimited, to output:

```
    C       D

1  her     RED

2  him     RED

3  jill    BLUE

4  kirk    RED

5          BLUE

6  rose    BLUE
```

Can you please help me with this? I assume I need excel to look through each cell in column 2, create databases for each comma delimited data point, then add to each database the column 1 color. Im not sure how to do that and output it.

Comment: Select column B, do `Text to Columns`, choose `Delimited`, choose `Comma` and click `Finish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reading the same question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1199293/macro-for-text-to-column-then-transposing-the-converted-text-to-columns-and-inse/1199383#1199383)

I assume that you inserted your file into excel:

```
Sub test()

Set iWsh = WorkSheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet containing raw data (text-file)
Set oWsh = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Sheet you wanted to have processed data in it

Set rng = [B1]
Set rng = Range(rng, Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

 rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                   ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                   Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False

i = 1
j = 2
k = 1

  While iWsh.Cells(i,1) <> "" ' Loops through rows of the data
    Do While iWsh.Cells(i,j) <> "" 'Loops through column of the data 

       oWsh.Cells(k,1) = iWsh.Cells(i,j)

       oWsh.Cells(k,2) = iWsh.Cells(i,1)

      k = k + 1
      j = j + 1

    Loop

     i = i + 1
     j = 2

  Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only seems to delimit the data cell within the same sheet. No sort and no output to the 2nd sheet.

Comment: @JasonCarroll Check it out now.